# SQL Version of a DOS Echo command?

Tags: sql, sql-server, echo

New to SQL and scripting, did a search and perhaps used incorrect wording, so I'm posting my question.  My script in MSFT Sql Server Mgmt Studio produces these message results:

(1566 row(s) affected)

(59 row(s) affected)

(1566 row(s) affected)

(1566 row(s) affected)

(262 row(s) affected)

Everything works, but I'd like to add a statement so if someone other than myself runs this script, they can tell whats going on, similar to the old Dos ECHO command in a batch file.  This way the results look something like this:

Backup table:
(1566 row(s) affected)

Update Merge Targets:
(59 row(s) affected)

Cleanup Old Table:
(1566 row(s) affected)

Export Historical:
(1566 row(s) affected)

Remove Blank Records:
(262 row(s) affected)

I don't care if they sit in the same row or above each affected statement, I just need some kind of labelling output.  Thanks all!

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176047.aspx

Answer (score 6):

An alternative to `PRINT` is to use [`RAISERROR()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178592.aspx). Strangely, given it's name, it's not just for error reporting.

`RAISERROR('message',10,1)` just reports information.

You can also add `WITH NOWAIT` at the end; this has the advantage that the message appears immediately. `PRINT` statements are buffered along with other messages and result sets, so if there's a long running task that happens after a particular `PRINT`, you may not actually see the `PRINT`ed message until that long running task has also finished<sup>1</sup>.

Also, of note, is that `RAISERROR()` includes some primitive `printf` style formatting features, whereas with `PRINT` you're stuck assembling the string yourself and performing `CONVERT` calls to convert non-string values into strings. E.g.:

```
RAISERROR (N'This is message %s %d.',10,1,N'number',5) WITH NOWAIT;
```

will print:

```
This is message number 5
```

to the messages window immediately.

---

<sup>1</sup>As an example, try running both of the following scripts. 1:

```
print 'abc'
print 'def'
waitfor delay '00:00:30'
print 'ghi'
```

and 2:

```
RAISERROR('abc',10,1) WITH NOWAIT
RAISERROR('def',10,1) WITH NOWAIT
waitfor delay '00:00:30'
RAISERROR('ghi',10,1) WITH NOWAIT
```

Both produce identical output:

```
abc
def
ghi
```

The difference between the two is that for script 1, you'll see no output for 30 seconds and then see all 3 lines, whereas for script two, you'll see:

```
abc
def
```

immediately and then, after 30 seconds, the final line will be shown.

Comment: Good to note!  I'll probably use print though, to help me understand the timing of my script.

Comment: @user2994079 - I'm not sure what you mean by timing. As I note in my answer, `print` is buffered whereas `RAISERROR ... WITH NOWAIT` is immediate. So if you need to know *when* things are happening, `PRINT` is the worse option.

Answer (score 1):

The command you are looking for is called `PRINT`

```
PRINT 'Lookie here!';
```

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176047.aspx

Comment: Thanks!  I'll try that with the next test batch.

Answer (score 1):

Between each statement you could `PRINT` and echo the `@@ROWCOUNT`

```
PRINT 'Backup Table: ' + CAST(@@ROWCOUNT AS NVARCHAR)
```

**For Example**

```
SET NOCOUNT ON

SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2
PRINT 'Backup Table: (' + CAST(@@ROWCOUNT AS NVARCHAR) + ' row(s) affected)'

SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3
PRINT 'Update Merge Targets: (' + CAST(@@ROWCOUNT AS NVARCHAR) + ' row(s) affected)'

SET NOCOUNT OFF
```

**Ouputs**

```
Backup Table: (2 row(s) affected)
Update Merge Targets: (3 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: Thats a good one to.  I'll save that for when I get farther down the line.  :-)